# Attribute of an object is undefined despite being assigned value

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So I am building a small game, and one of the characters is this Golem object:

```
function Golem(){
    var self = this;
    this.width = 470;
    this.height = 360;
    this.drawX = canvasEntities.width/3;
    this.speed = 30;
    this.isLeftKey = false;
    this.isRightKey = false;
    this.isSpacebar = false;
    this.spritesheet = spritesheetgolemleft;
    this.animate = function(){
        requestAnimFrame(self.animate);
        //this console log returns undefined
        console.log(self.spritesheet)
        this.spritesheet.update();
        self.spritesheet.draw(self.drawX,canvasEntities.height/3);
    }
}
```

the spritesheetgolemleft variable was already defined at the very top(global):

```
var spritesheetgolemleft = new SpriteSheet('images/golem_walkleft.png',470,360,3,6);
```

And here is the SpriteSheet class:

```
function SpriteSheet(path, frameWidth, frameHeight, frameSpeed, endFrame){
    var image = new Image();
    var framesPerRow,
            currentFrame = 0,
            counter = 0;
    //# of frames after image loads
    var self = this;
    image.onload = function(){
        framesPerRow = Math.floor(image.width/frameWidth);
    };
    image.src = path;
    this.update = function(){
        if(counter == (frameSpeed - 1))
            currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % endFrame;
        counter = (counter + 1) % frameSpeed;
    }
    this.draw = function(x,y){
        var row = Math.floor(currentFrame / framesPerRow);
        var col = Math.floor(currentFrame % framesPerRow);
        //draw image into the Entities canvas
        ctxEntities.drawImage(
            image,
            col * frameWidth, row*frameHeight,
            frameWidth, frameHeight,
            x,y,
            frameWidth, frameHeight);
    };
};
```

The error I am getting happens in the second to last line of the Golem() object:

this.spritesheet.update();

It is giving me a TypeError, cannot read property 'update' of undefined. Thinking it was some sort of issue with scopes, I added the self = this hack at the top, but it still does not work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had it as self.spritesheet.update() before, but it didn't work.

Comment: You should change it back to self.spritesheet.update() for sure. Could it be a cache issue? I created a jsfiddle, that seems to run fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ed32j0tr/ - it logs self.spritesheet to the console just fine...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was instantiating an object before creating the spritesheets. My mistake :/